# Split a particular month into weeks and days

Tags: sql-server, telerik

Suppose I took the month November.I need to display first row as shown below.The rest of the rows should be the data from database.The rows display post date and amount and if data is present on those dates,it should be shown.I also need to show the weekly totals and monthly totals of the amounts taken.This is shown for a PARTICULAR MONTH of a PARTICULAR YEAR.
I was planning to write a query for the data and implement it in **Telerik** via **crosstab**.Please give your thoughts on the same.
Input:-

```
POST DATE                Amount($)
2013-11-01 00:00:00.000  50.00
2013-11-04 09:30:12.000  10.00
2013-11-05 11:04:00.000  20.00
2013-11-06 00:00:00.000  30.00
2013-11-07 00:00:00.000  40.00
2013-11-08 00:00:00.000  10.00
2013-11-11 00:00:00.000  10.00
2013-11-12 00:00:00.000  10.00
2013-11-15 00:00:00.000  10.00
.
.
.
```

The data(for the month November) should be visible like this:-

```
01-Nov  Weekly Total    04-Nov  05-Nov  06-Nov  07-Nov  08-Nov  Weekly Total    11-Nov  12-Nov  13-Nov  14-Nov  15-Nov  Weekly Total    18-Nov  19-Nov  20-Nov  21-Nov  22-Nov  Weekly Total    25-Nov  26-Nov  27-Nov  29-Nov  Weekly Total    MTD Total
50$       50$             10$    20$     30$     40$      10$     110$            10$     10$                    10$       30$
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN Date and Time Data Types and Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx)

```
DECLARE @TempTrans AS Table (
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,DateTimeTrans DATETIME NOT NULL
    ,Amount MONEY NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @TempTrans (DateTimeTrans, Amount)
VALUES ('20131101', 50)
    ,('20131104 09:30:12',10)
    ,('20131104 11:04:00',15)
    ,('20131105',20)
    ,('20131106',30)
    ,('20131111',10)
    ,('20131115',80)
    ,('20131119',70)
    ,('20131123',60)
    ,('20111129 10:08:04',25)

SELECT *
    ,CASE
        WHEN [weekNumber] IS NULL AND [Date] IS NULL THEN 'MTD Total'
        WHEN [Date] IS NULL THEN 'Weekly Total'
        ELSE CAST([Date] as varchar(30)) 
    END as [Description]
FROM (
    SELECT DATEPART(week,DateTimeTrans) as weekNumber,CAST(DateTimeTrans as date) as Date, SUM(Amount) as Amount
    FROM @TempTrans
    WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,DateTimeTrans) = 11
    GROUP BY DATEPART(week,DateTimeTrans) ,CAST(DateTimeTrans as date)
    WITH Rollup
) grp
GO
```

Comment: I need to split the dates as shown above.Suppose if we take November as the month,nov 1st is a Friday,so nov 1st should be shown and then the weekly total.Similarly the next 5 day's amounts should be shown and then the weekly total of that week.I need to show all the weeks amounts and total(even if there are 6 weeks in total).Month divide by 4 and then splitting onto weeks cannot be used in this case.   Thank you

Comment: @user3030293 Ok, just remove `DATEPART(MONTH,DateTimeTrans)` from `select, group by, order by` and you will get the result. Or not? Maybe I do not understand you correctly about 6 weeks. Try to formulate the question more precisely. Examples of the data and the desired result.

Comment: The input details is now added along with the question.Thanks.